# Calling onResume in Android's activity

Tags: android, call, onresume

is it ok in an activity's procedure to force the onResume event by calling this.OnResume() ? Or should I implement another procedure that's called by both OnResume and by the first member ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement another procedure that's called in your override of `onResume()`. The latter is not intended to be called by you, it's a convenience method that tidies up or readies the activity when its state changes to `resume`. A lot like `onCreate()` through to `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

What @SK9 said, but also especially because you *must* call super.onResume() when you override the onResume method, so you're not in control what happens in the background (views getting refreshed, etc).