# Cannot activate onResume() from DatePickerFragment

Tags: java, android

I have called onResume() to update my display after user enters a date via DatePickerDialog. This works. However in a new version I am using DatePickerFragment and this does no longer works.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) 
 {  // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    userSetYear=year;
    userSetMonth=month;
    userSetDay=day;
    userSetDate=true;
    onResume(); //activates the wrong onResume, has no affect on display
    //MainActivity.onResume();//error message : Cannot make a static reference to          the     non-static method onResume() from the type MainActivity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onResume() method should not be called by you, it is about the life cycle of the activity itself.
But here is a link for you: [Calling onResume in Android's activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012171/calling-onresume-in-androids-activity)

Also you may want to read about the life cycle management in Android ; http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Well, that doesn't point me in any direction that I can discern. Therefore, I don't see why the answer was provided.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that, calling life cycle methods for view updates is not a good approach, therefore wanted to provide a useful link for a better understanding. Maybe I should have used comments, sorry.

Comment: OK, thanks, anyway, there is a clear technical question posed  by comparing the last two lines of the code.  I would be happy to decompose onResume() if I knew a recommended approach. Even if I did, however, I think I would still have the original problem left by making a call from the fragment version of onDateSet().